# iOS: In what precise directory are crash logs stored on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, crash-reports

We need to upload the core dump and/or crash log from an app crash that is occurring on an iOS device. My question is: In what directory on the device can I find that file? The device is deployed **remotely**, so I cannot immediately connect it to a Mac to retrieve info about the crash via Xcode, and we do not have a crash manager like Crashlytics running on the device. We do however have a person using the device (it's an iPad) who can install another app that can upload files that it's allowed to access.

Answer (score 0):

To access the crash report files via an app, the device needs to be jailbroken, otherwise it is not possible to access the location using an app due to app sandboxing.

To access the crash report without jailbreaking the device, you can follow these steps (for iOS 7):

1. Open the settings app
2. Select the `General` menu
3. Select `About`
4. Select `Diagnostics & Usage`
5. Select `Diagnostic & Usage Data`
6. Search in the list of files for an entry that starts with your apps name, followed by a date and select that entry
7. Mark the full text of the report and copy it to the clipboard
8. Create a new mail, paste the copied text and send it